Compatibility between Vue 3 named slots and Sitecore dynamic placeholders
Is it possible to insert a sitecore dynamic placeholder inside a vue 3 named slot?
I found that because of vue 3 named slot template syntax, sitecore can't find the placeholders correctly and the select rendering screen doesn't show correctly.
I implemented the suggestion in this post
It works for a non-named slot, but for named slots, it doesn't.

What even is Sitecore? Looks quite complex overall.
